# Filename matching, extension not important

Tags: ruby

I want to write a method that does this

```
def search_for_filenames(dir, name)
    # goes to the directory and returns a list of files that match
    # the given name, regardless of extension
end
```

So for example if the name was `test`, and my directory contained the following

```
test.png
test.txt
something_else.dat
```

The method will return an array containing the first two filenames

How can I write this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Dir::glob`.

```
Dir::glob("#{dir}/#{name}.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough it would be faster then `Dir::glob` but it actually can take more time to run sometimes. Anyway, here is what I have done. But use `Dir::glob`.

```
def search_for_filenames(dir, name)
  result_files = []
  Dir.new(dir).each do |file|
    if /^#{name}\.\w+$/.match file
      result_files << file
      return result_files if result_files.size == 2
    end
  end
  result_files
end
```

Comment: Hmm I might explore alternative ways to do it if I have time but for now I used glob.

Comment: glob should be always faster since it's done all  in C whether my way has more ruby to be converted to C. But i'm just guessing. Dont take this seriously